# how to remove all duplicate values from a column

Tags: 2013, custom-list, duplicate

For some reason when a user is adding a record, it duplicates it three times.

Why is that happening?

[image]

Since there is many How can I remove any records that contains a duplicate in a specific column?

Comment: do you have the any workflow on the list or any other customization?

Comment: another thing, i am thinking if you enforce Uniqueness on the JPPNum column then duplicate can avoide

Comment: I was thinking that but I already have a lot of duplicates, which I need to remove first. so I can do the unquiness option.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities

1. A workflow
2. Event Receiver

Workflow you can check using SharePoint Designer.

Event Receiver - You can download SharePoint Manager and connect to SharePoint server or you can use below PS script

```
$site = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://siteurl"
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list = $web.Lists["ListName"]
$list.EventReceivers | Select assembly, name, type
```

Comment: what kind of workflow would it be?

Comment: Not sure you can check List Settings -> Workflows and see what all workflows are associated

Comment: where would the ps script go

Comment: You need to login to Server and open SharePoint Management Shell and execute it

Comment: I don't have access to the management

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some kind of Workflow or Event receiver can cause this issue.

you  can avoid this in future to implement the Uniqueness on the column.

[Enforcing Uniqueness in Column Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee536168(v=office.14).aspx)

Now to remove the Duplicate values from list, couple of options.

Option # 1

- Make sure all item are at least major version and checked in.
- Create a fresh view without any filter and display all claims.
- Export to excel
- Try to to run excel ->Data -> Remove duplicate
- See is there any duplicate removed or not

Option # 2

Please try to open this list as access(link in IE) and run this query in access

```
SELECT Claim.[Claim Number], Count(*) AS Expr1
FROM Claim
GROUP BY Claim.[Claim Number]
HAVING (((Count(*))>1));
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/1fbe7492-418d-4242-a9d3-ee550115affe/this-field-contains-duplicate-values-remove-all-duplicate-values-and-try-the-operation-again?forum=sharepointcustomization

Comment: I did option 1 and theres 300 duplicates but scarrtered through out the view. so theres no way to do a specific filter

Comment: also check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21331530/sharepoint-2013-lists-remove-duplicates-from-list-view

Comment: Does anyone know why when a certain user adds a new record, it is being duplicated but it happens randomly. no event receiver or workflow.